# Webkit transition without hover

Tags: html, css

I have made the following simple animation where an image grows on mouse hover, but what I really want is for it to occur without the  hover, ie when the page loads.

HTML

```
    <div id="first" class="animated grow"><img src="images/sunflower.png"></div>
```

CSS

```
        /* GROW ANIMATION */
.grow img {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 400px;
  width: 160px;

  -webkit-transition: all 5s ease;
     -moz-transition: all 5s ease;
       -o-transition: all 5s ease;
      -ms-transition: all 5s ease;
          transition: all 5s ease;

}

.grow img:hover {
  width: 200px;
  height: 500px;
}
```

I tried using the following but it doesn't work.

```
from {width: 160px; height: 400px;}
to {width: 200px; height: 500px;}
```

Either its the wrong way to go or I am not placing in the right place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Here you go:**

```
animation: imganim 1s infinite linear both;

@keyframes imganim {
from {width: 160px; height: 400px;}
to {width: 200px; height: 500px;} 
}
```

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/42gbhcb6/)**

**and for looping animation use this:**

```
@keyframes imganim {
0% {width: 160px; height: 400px;}
50% {width: 200px; height: 500px;}
100% {width: 160px; height: 400px;}
}
```

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/42gbhcb6/1/)**

**notes:**

- no need to use `transition` for `animation`
- for define animation you should use `keyframes`
- already all modern browser read `animation` or `transition` there is no need to use `-webkit-` or `-moz-` or etc.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is an `animation`, not a `transition`. On the element you want the animation on, you give the animation a name (i.e. **animate**) and put the animation variables inside that keyframe animation. See below for the full layout. Don't forget the vendor prefixes.

```css
/* GROW ANIMATION */
.grow img {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 400px;
  width: 160px;
  -webkit-animation: animate 5s ease-in;  
  animation: animate 5s ease-in;
}

@-webkit-keyframes animate {
  from {
    width: 160px; 
    height: 400px;
  }
  to {
    width: 200px; 
    height: 500px;
  } 
}
@keyframes animate {
  from {
    width: 160px; 
    height: 400px;
  }
  to {
    width: 200px; 
    height: 500px;
  } 
}
```

```html
<div id="first" class="animated grow"><img src="http://dummyimage.com/400x160"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have **@keyframes** and **duration** in your CSS, something like this:

```
@keyframes example {
  from {background-color: red;}
  to {background-color: yellow;}
}

/* The element to apply the animation to */
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  animation-name: example;
  animation-duration: 4s;
}
```

Replace the color values with the height/width values you want.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution: the transition rule is not written properly to obtain that behaviour.

```css
.grow img {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 400px;
  width: 160px;
  animation-timing-function: ease; 
 /* -webkit-transition: fadein all 5s;
     -moz-transition: fadein all 5s;
       -o-transition: fadein all 5s;
      -ms-transition: fadein all 5s;
          transition: fadein all 5s;*/
          
    animation-name: fadein;
    animation-duration: 4s;

}

@keyframes fadein {
    from {width: 160px; height: 400px;}
to {width: 200px; height: 500px;} 
}


/* Firefox < 16 */
@-moz-keyframes fadein {
    from {width: 160px; height: 400px;}
to {width: 200px; height: 500px;} 
}

/* Safari, Chrome and Opera > 12.1 */
@-webkit-keyframes fadein {
    from {width: 160px; height: 400px;}
to {width: 200px; height: 500px;} 
}

/* Internet Explorer */
@-ms-keyframes fadein {
    from {width: 160px; height: 400px;}
to {width: 200px; height: 500px;} 
}

/* Opera < 12.1 */
@-o-keyframes fadein {
   from {width: 160px; height: 400px;}
to {width: 200px; height: 500px;} 
}
```

```html
 <div id="first" class="animated grow"><img src="images/sunflower.png"></div>
```